# Hamiltonian of a free particle in spherical coordinates

Tags: classical-mechanics, acceleration, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian

Why would the hamiltonian, expressed in spherical coordinates, give a free partucle a non-zero acceleration in the radial direction? I'm learning it from Liboff's quantum mechanics book and he says it's because of the inappropriate choice of coordinate system, but I still don't get it.

Comment: It would be useful if you referenced the exact chapter/page of the book or, even better, included a small quote to make this question self contained.

Comment: This may also be helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/558668/